# Dictionary access optimization describen - does it take place anywhere?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, dictionary, hashtable

Most of us compiler nerds have read Google's paper on V8 object property access where the resulting technique is just (in-)directly accessing an array member. My question is:

Does anyone optimize the dictionary access the same way (assigning a fixed index to a (compile time) fixed key)? It doesn't have to be applicable everywhere but perhaps when it's compilation-unit wide? Or the dictionary is readonly? Or between the compilation units at a pass? Whatever, maybe even unrolling the dict. access or inlineing it using a *fixed array index instead of a key*.

I do know how constant time lookup dictionaries work, but maybe the proposed optimization takes place to further boost the compiled languages (e.g. C++) where the hardware is coached to deal with V-table-like structures at runtime.

Please, if you know any of that, give me a hunch. Thank you much!

TL;DR I want to know of an existing way to optimize *dictionary* access, (e.g. accessing `std::map` via array index), not of internal struct/object arrangment in a particular language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Doubtful**

While this could in theory be possible (being that `std::map` implementation is part of the Standard library) I know of no C++ compiler that performs such a trick.

And they do not really have to: if you want array indexing in C++, you pick an array and index it (possibly with named constants).

Comment: one could possibly want to use a dictionary when the key has to be e.g. string _at runtime_ and the size is indefinite. I'm totally theorizing but maybe there's a small chance that the compile time known access to such a dictionary could be speed up by what I have describen. And BTW =) I've seen MSVC99 or so completely transforming std::vector read access to a single `lea` instruction followed by a `mov`

Comment: @rostamn739: do note, though, that `vector` is a dynamic array, whereas `map` is a binary search tree. Optimizing an array read into a simple array read is quite simpler.